# Kargath Bladefist Aggro Reset

Tags: world-of-warcraft

We were fighting Kargath Bladefist on Mythic lately and something really annyoing happened throughout the fights: He was randomly switching Targets during his Berserker Rush.

Now since you should kite kargath as long as possible during his Berserker Rush in mythic difficulty we also tried it. When a hunter or mage was targeted by the ability we also used Deterrence or Ice Block (Note that none of those two dropped the aggro). The main problem was that Kargath would sometimes reset his target and chop through the raid, onehitting everyone within seconds.

What is the cause of this aggro switch? I hear a lot of things in the forums. The most common ones are that it happens if someone (not the target) dies or that it's simply a bug.

Comment: Can't confirm exactly what causes it, but I also **[read](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1657061-Kargath-mythic-changes-target-while-Berserker-Rush?p=31207747#post31207747)** that it was due to someone else other than the target dying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did some research on this because we had the exact same issue. We had few attempts where we thought it was because of warlock gateways. Which as you mentioned, gave the exact same result.

Our conclusion was the follwing:

There seem to be 2 criteria for Kargath to drop his Berserker Rush and switch to a new target.

- Target player dies during Berserker Rush
- Any player dies by Beserker Rush while the targeted player is kiting Kargath.

The way we dealt with this was simple.
All classes with the exception of hunters and mage kite the boss through the fire.

Hunters and mages pop Iceblock / Deterrence before the boss would reach them.
Have a paladin use [Hand of Protection](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1022) about 1 second before Iceblock or Deterrence would end.
Hunters would pop their second deterrence before the end of hand of protection.

This would allow you to soak a full Beserker Rush.
Ofcourse this would require you to have a paladin with you in the raid with [Clemency](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=105622) talent.

This does mean you would hardly gain any favor from the crowd unless a hunter or mage would get fixated. (we had 2 mages and 3 hunter)
Doing it this way really depends on your setup.

Comment: This also reminds me of SoO raids where trash mobs would blindly charge a random raid member then use weapon attacks on people when he ran back to the tank.